# Can't export full image album to my computer picture file

Tags: images

I've used Picasa since its inception to organize my photos. I have learned how to export my organized albums back to a single picture file on my computer so I can create "photo books" for my grandkids, etc.  I currently have a "huge" Picasa album that I created by using the Google facial recognition tool.  This album contains 1000+ images....but just shows the face and not the entire picture it was taken from.  When I export this album to the picture file folder on my computer it only shows the face and not the picture so I obviously can't use this for my photo album book I'm making.  These 1000+ images were originally located in probably 100+ different file folders on my computer.  How do I get these "full" images in one file folder on my computer from this Picasa album that was created using the Google facial recognition tool?  HELP!!!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.